# Detailed distance between words

Tags: edit-distance

How would I go about displaying detailed distance between words.
For example, the output of the program could be:

```
Words are "car" and "cure":
Replace "a" with "u".
Add "e".
```

The Levenshtein distance does not fulfill my needs (I think).

Comment: I think then, that you need to give a more precise definition of "distance", in the way that you're using it.

Comment: What is wrong with Levenshtein distance?

Comment: I need to output what is being done in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. The algorithm is roughly following [Wikipedia (Levenshtein distance)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). The language used below is **ruby**

Use as an example, the case of changing `s` into `t` as follows:

```
s = 'Sunday'
t = 'Saturday'
```

First, `s` and `t` are turned into arrays, and an empty string is inserted at the beginning. `m` will eventually be the matrix used in the argorithm.

```
s = ['', *s.split('')]
t = ['', *t.split('')]
m = Array.new(s.length){[]}
```

`m` here, however, is different from the matrix given if the algorithm in wikipedia for the fact that each cell includes not only the **Levenshtein distance**, but also the (non-)operation (**starting**, **doing nothing**, **deletion**, **insertion**, or **substitution**) that was used to get to that cell from an adjacent (left, up, or upper-left) cell. It may also include a **string** describing the parameters of the operation. That is, the format of each cell is:

[Levenshtein distance, operation(, string)]

Here is the main routine. It fills in the cells of `m` following the algorithm:

```
s.each_with_index{|a, i| t.each_with_index{|b, j|
    m[i][j] =
    if i.zero?
        [j, "started"]
    elsif j.zero?
        [i, "started"]
    elsif a == b
        [m[i-1][j-1][0], "did nothing"]
    else
        del, ins, subs = m[i-1][j][0], m[i][j-1][0], m[i-1][j-1][0]
        case [del, ins, subs].min
        when del
            [del+1, "deleted", "'#{a}' at position #{i-1}"]
        when ins
            [ins+1, "inserted", "'#{b}' at position #{j-1}"]
        when subs
            [subs+1, "substituted", "'#{a}' at position #{i-1} with '#{b}'"]
        end
    end
}}
```

Now, we set `i`, `j` to the bottom-right corner of `m` and follow the steps backwards as we unshift the contents of the cell into an array called `steps`, until we reach the start.

```
i, j = s.length-1, t.length-1
steps = []
loop do
    case m[i][j][1]
    when "started"
        break
    when "did nothing", "substituted"
        steps.unshift(m[i-=1][j-=1])
    when "deleted"
        steps.unshift(m[i-=1][j])
    when "inserted"
        steps.unshift(m[i][j-=1])
    end
end
```

Then we print the operation and the string of each step unless that is a non-operation.

```
steps.each do |d, op, str=''|
    puts "#{op} #{str}" unless op == "did nothing" or op == "started"
end
```

With this particular example, it will output:

```
inserted 'a' at position 1
inserted 't' at position 2
substituted 'n' at position 2 with 'r'
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but I must have had something wrong. I ended up with doing some bruteforcing.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
   def solve(self, text, word0, word1):
      word_list = text.split()
      ans = len(word_list)
      L = None
      for R in range(len(word_list)):
         if word_list[R] == word0 or word_list[R] == word1:
            if L is not None and word_list[R] != word_list[L]:
               ans = min(ans, R - L - 1)
               L = R
      return -1 if ans == len(word_list) else ans
ob = Solution()
text = "cat dog abcd dog cat cat abcd dog wxyz"
word0 = "abcd"
word1 = "wxyz"
print(ob.solve(text, word0, word1))
```